# How to print * in middle character of string array element if length is odd

Tags: php, arrays

I want to print * in middle element of odd element of array. here is my code I'm not getting what is the condition I'm write on inner loop? if character length is 7 then how i print * on 4 number character.?

```
 $strings = array("abcdef","abcde","qwert","abcdef","bat");

 for ($i=0; $i <count($strings) ; $i++) { 

 $len = strlen($strings[$i]);

 if($len % 2 == 0)
  {
 echo "Chacater's are even<br>";
  }
else{

 $string = $strings[$i];

 for($j=0; $j<1; $j++)
 {
    $string[$j] = "*";
  }
echo $string."<br>";
  }

  }
```

Comment: can you show for example

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Where do you want to print *? And are you reffering to the length of the array? or array elements?

Comment: in array if the string element length is odd then * print on middle character of odd string. i didn't get the logic how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to my understanding you need to replace the middle char of an odd length element in the array with '*'. This  code will give you the desired results.

```
$strings = array("abcdef","abcde","qwert","abcdef");
    $count = count($strings);

    for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) { 
        $len = strlen($strings[$i]);
        if($len % 2 == 0){
            echo "Chacater's are even \n";
        }else{
            $string = $strings[$i];
            // find the center index
            $center = floor($len/2);
            // replace the center char with *
            $string = substr_replace($string, '*', $center,1);
            echo $string."\n";
        }
      }
```

Out put :

```
Chacater's are even 
ab*de
qw*rt
Chacater's are even
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to do like this

```
 <?php 
  $strings = array("abcdef","abcde","qwert","abcdef");
  foreach($strings as $key=> $value){
     $strlen = strlen($value);
     if($strlen%2 == 0){
       echo "\n".$value." :even length";
     }else {
       if($strlen > 1){
         $value[intVal($strlen/2)]="*";
       }
       echo "\n".$value." :odd length";
     }
  }
 ?>
```

Demo : https://eval.in/850350

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1270a1e27b1148e4381ac7882a747ba592b328dc